# Is it grammatically correct to use comma in this manner "You will get a XX that is nice and clean, ready for further processing"?

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically correct to use comma in this manner :

> "You will get a product that is nice and clean, ready for further processing" ?

My colleague said it is wrong. Is it true?

Comment: What is an "XX",  please use the actual word and don't replace it with XX.

Comment: it could be result, outcome or product.

Comment: Which one?  What did you actually say to your colleague? The actual words that you used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be okay in speech, but not in writing.

You mean the item will be "nice and clean" and also it will be "ready for processing", there is a list of two items, so we normally would link these with "and".  However, in this case, that would look odd because the first item in the list already has "and".

This is a situation in which an "Oxford comma" could be useful:

> You will get a product that is nice and clean, and ready for further processing.

However, do you *really* need to say "nice"? It is a "weak modifier" it doesn't add much information to the sentence.  It's not really possible for it to be "clean but not nice".  So drop the word "nice". Then the Oxford comma is not needed.

> You will get a product that is clean and ready for further processing.

Alternatively: "You will get a nice and clean product that is ready for further processing."

Comment: Alternatively, *You will get a nice and clean product that is ready for further processing*. (Is this a situation where a compound adjective can be hyphenated to nice-and-clean?)

Comment: That is a good suggestion, and it demonstrates how using the actual words in the question instead of "XX" can help find effective alternate solutions.

Comment: According to Cambridge the example is incorrect; Quote: Warning: Apart from two-word conjunctions, we only use one conjunction to connect words or phrases: This is a rule that was always taught in schools in my day and is still applicable.

Comment: How would you ask for "fish and chips, and a pie and chips" (The answer is not "Fish, chips, a pie and chips").  You are taking a rule far too literally.  "Nice and clean" forms a single item, much like "fish and chips".  However please write your own answer.

Comment: @Smock It's not necessary to hyphenate it at all.

Comment: @James K: two portions of chips a pie and that battered cod at the end. Oh! and 2 cartons of mushy peas! Plenty of salt but easy on the vinegar.

Comment: @James K sorry the wife's changed her mind. Half a Cod and Chips on a tray, no salt and vinegar. A portion of chips, a pastie, plenty of salt but easy on the vinegar.  A large curry sauce a small carton of mushy peas and some batter bits, if you have any.

Answer (score -1):

"You will get a product that is nice and clean, ready for further processing" 
**Is it grammatically correct to use comma in this manner?**

It would be acceptable in speech, but **not in writing**.

You have two phrases "nice and clean" and  "ready for processing", this is a list of two items, so we normally would link these with "and" as I have shown above. However, that would sound wrong because we have already used "and". There is a rule, Apart from two-word conjunctions, we only use one conjunction to connect words or phrases. That is, **One "And" in a sentence** (although it is often broken, especially in spoken English). [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/linking-words-and-expressions/conjunctions)

This is a situation in which a "comma" could be useful, to **replace** the first **"and"** but better still would be to **rephrase** the sentence to **use only one "and"** or **even omit the use of "and"** altogether.

"**You will get a clean, high quality product that is ready for further processing.**"

**Note** I have **removed** the word **nice** as it adds nothing to this sentence. I presume you are trying to emphasis it is a **good product**. In this case high quality would be more descriptive.

> **Conjunctions** [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/linking-words-and-expressions/conjunctions)
>
> Conjunctions are linking words like and, or, but, then and because:
>
> **Warning**:
>   Apart from two-word conjunctions, **we only use one conjunction to connect words or phrases:**
>
> **Because my alarm didn’t go off, I was late for work**. Not: **Because** my alarm didn’t go off, **so** I was late for work.